# Why does pyQGIS QgsVectorLayer().isValid() return FALSE with Oracle views?

Tags: pyqgis, oracle-spatial

This works perfectly fine with an Oracle TABLE but not with a VIEW. Why?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection(host, port, db, username, pw)
uri.setWkbType(QGis.WKBPolygon)
uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geomcol)
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), table, 'oracle')
print vlayer.isValid()
```

..and returns TRUE. However, the same code does not work with a VIEW. Both TABLE and VIEW have correct entry in USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA. All spatial tables in the database load correctly; none of the views do.
All spatial tables and views load correctly in QGIS using Layer->Add Layer->Add Oracle Spatial Layer. Is it meant to work only with tables or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think I meant QgsVectorLayer() in the title, not QgsDataSourceURI().

Comment: ...and vlayer.isValid() returns FALSE with views; TRUE with tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For VIEWS you have to define the column which uniquely identify features for the layer, try to add:

```py
uri.setKeyColumn("your_unique_field")
```

Comment: I tried uri.setKeyColumn("your_unique_field") with a numeric and unique values column but unfortunately it does not work. These views have no primary key and Oracle does not require one either. I would like to know whether this is meant to work with Oracle views at all. Is there anybody who did this successfully?

Comment: Ok, it works but only if uri.setKeyColumn() follows uri.setDataSource(). Answer accepted! I now have another problem: stopping the 'coordinate reference system selector' popping up; uri.setSrid() and vlayer.setCrs() won't prevent it popping up... I'll try harder. Thanks for the uri.setKeyColumn() advice.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("doracle1.aytomalaga.intranet", "dbd3", "eqgis", "eqgis")

uri.setSrid ('25830');
uri.setDataSource('EQGIS','MSEQESLU_V', 'SDOGEOMETRIA', '', 'ID_EQESLU')

uri.setWkbType(QGis.WKBMultiPoint)

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"capa", 'oracle')
```

You need to choose the version with five parameters of setDataSource.